# Make drawer responsive in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this drawer in Flutter, the problem is when I resize the screen, the text(drawer) keeps on breaking in two lines or more (ending with a letter in each row).
How can I stop the screen from resize, or is there any other solution ?
I've been looking at `LayoutBuilder` but I don't think it's going to do the job because I don't have another drawer to use on smaller screens.

> I'm building this for Windows Desktop or Web, not mobile.

```
 class DrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerListTile({
    Key key, @required this.title,@required this.svgSrc,@required this.press1,@required this.press2,@required this.press3,@required this.subTitle1,@required this.subTitle2,@required this.subTitle3
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title,svgSrc,subTitle1,subTitle2,subTitle3;
  final VoidCallback press1,press2,press3;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      leading: SvgPicture.asset(
        svgSrc,
        color: Colors.black,
        height:16,
      ),
      title: Text(title),
      children: [

        ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:30),
          onTap:press1,
          horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
          leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_right_rounded,color:Colors.black),
          title:Text(
            subTitle1,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 15),
          ),

        ),
        ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:30),
          onTap:press2,
          horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
          leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_right_rounded,color:Colors.black),
          title:Text(
            subTitle2,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 15),
          ),

        ),
        ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:30),
          onTap:press3,
          horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
          leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_right_rounded,color:Colors.black),
          title:Text(
            subTitle3,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 15),
          ),

        ),
      ],
    );

     
  }
}
```

Comment: If you like to fit the text in one line, You can use `FittedBox` or `AutoTextSize` or if you like clip use max line property

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the issue is around the text itself - in which case you can use this package [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) to control the text size and prevent it from breaking into 2 lines.

Same as @Yeasin Sheikh's comment